# MySQL get two recent records after join

Tags: mysql, database, select, mysql-5.7

I am trying to get the two recent comments for each post on my list. For that, I have a posts table like the following.

```
+----+-------------+------------+
| id |    post     |    date    |
+----+-------------+------------+
| 1  | First post  | 2020-01-01 |
| 2  | Second post | 2020-01-02 |
| 3  | Third post  | 2020-01-03 |
| 4  | Fourth post | 2020-01-04 |
+----+-------------+------------+
```

And another table of comments for the post as follows

```
+----+---------------------+---------+------------+
| id |       comment       | post_id |    date    |
+----+---------------------+---------+------------+
| 1  |   Comment 1 post 1  |    1    | 2020-01-01 |
| 2  |   Comment 2 post 1  |    1    | 2020-01-02 |
| 3  |   Comment 1 post 2  |    2    | 2020-01-02 |
| 4  |   Comment 2 post 2  |    2    | 2020-01-03 |
| 5  |   Comment 3 post 2  |    2    | 2020-01-04 |
| 6  |   Comment 4 post 2  |    2    | 2020-01-05 |
| 7  |   Comment 1 post 3  |    3    | 2020-01-03 |
+----+---------------------+---------+------------+
```

I would like to get the following results based on these tables

```
+---------+---------------------+-----------+------------+------------------+--------------+
| post_id |       post          | post_date | comment_id |       comment    | comment_date |
+---------+---------------------+-----------+------------+------------------+--------------+
|      1  |    First post       | 2020-01-01|     1      | Comment 1 post 1 |  2020-01-01  |
|      1  |    First post       | 2020-01-01|     2      | Comment 2 post 1 |  2020-01-02  |
|      2  |    Second post      | 2020-01-02|     5      | Comment 3 post 2 |  2020-01-04  |
|      2  |    Second post      | 2020-01-02|     6      | Comment 4 post 2 |  2020-01-05  |
|      3  |    Third post       | 2020-01-03|     7      | Comment 1 post 3 |  2020-01-03  |
|      3  |    Third post       | 2020-01-03|    NULL    |       NULL       |     NULL     |
|      4  |    Fourth post      | 2020-01-04|    NULL    |       NULL       |     NULL     |
|      4  |    Fourth post      | 2020-01-04|    NULL    |       NULL       |     NULL     |
+---------+---------------------+-----------+------------+------------------+--------------+
```

I'm able to find all the posts along with the most recent comment using the following query. However, finding the two comments is something I'm struggling with.

```
SELECT p.id AS p_id, p.post,p.date AS post_date,
c.id AS comment_id, c.comment, c.date AS comment_date 
FROM posts AS p
LEFT JOIN comments AS c ON c.post_id = p.id AND c.id = (
    SELECT ci.id
    FROM comments AS ci
    WHERE ci.post_id = p.id
    ORDER BY ci.date DESC
    LIMIT 0,1 
)
ORDER BY p.date DESC;
```

The MySQL version I'm using is 5.7. I've tried multiple join/union, but I'm looking for a better option if available.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What MySQL version you have? Since MySQL 8.0 helpful window functions introduced

Comment: MySql 5.7 is the version I'm using

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 5.7, assuming that `comments(id)` can be used to order the rows, you can use a correlated subquery in the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN` for filtering.

```
SELECT p.id AS p_id, p.post,p.date AS post_date,
    c.id AS comment_id, c.comment, c.date AS comment_date 
FROM posts AS p
LEFT JOIN comments AS c 
    ON c.post_id = p.id 
    AND (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM comments c1 
        WHERE c1.post_id = c.post_id AND c1.id >= c.id
    ) <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by next query (only MySQL 8.0 or later):

```
select 
    posts.*,
    comments.*
from posts 
join (
    select 2 number union select 1
) comment_numbers
left join (
  select 
      id comment_id,
      post_id,
      comment,
      date comment_date,
      row_number() over (partition by post_id order by date desc) as comment_number
  from comments
) comments on comments.post_id = posts.id and comment_number = comment_numbers.number
order by posts.id, coalesce(comment_number, 0) desc, number desc;
```

Result on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=75847019ac4ec8fc17e1994efe71baa0&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80):

```
+====+=============+============+============+=========+==================+==============+================+
| id | post        | date       | comment_id | post_id | comment          | comment_date | comment_number |
+====+=============+============+============+=========+==================+==============+================+
| 1  | First post  | 2020-01-01 | 1          | 1       | Comment 1 post 1 | 2020-01-01   | 2              |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------------+--------------+----------------+
| 1  | First post  | 2020-01-01 | 2          | 1       | Comment 2 post 1 | 2020-01-02   | 1              |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------------+--------------+----------------+
| 2  | Second post | 2020-01-02 | 5          | 2       | Comment 3 post 2 | 2020-01-04   | 2              |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------------+--------------+----------------+
| 2  | Second post | 2020-01-02 | 6          | 2       | Comment 4 post 2 | 2020-01-05   | 1              |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------------+--------------+----------------+
| 3  | Third post  | 2020-01-03 | 7          | 3       | Comment 1 post 3 | 2020-01-03   | 1              |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------------+--------------+----------------+
| 3  | Third post  | 2020-01-03 | (null)     | (null)  | (null)           | (null)       | (null)         |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------------+--------------+----------------+
| 4  | Fourth post | 2020-01-04 | (null)     | (null)  | (null)           | (null)       | (null)         |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------------+--------------+----------------+
| 4  | Fourth post | 2020-01-04 | (null)     | (null)  | (null)           | (null)       | (null)         |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+---------+------------------+--------------+----------------+
```